# Split | character in string

Tags: apex, split

Is there a way I can split | character in a string?

I'm trying with

```
myString.split('|')
```

but it's not working.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply escape the | with:

```
String myString = 'one|two';
myString.split('\\|');
```

Comment: The reason why it needs to be escaped is because the `.split()` method takes a _regular expresssion_ as its input. `|` has a special meaning in regex, so to split on a literal `|` we need to escape it. Regexes in Apex require double backslash to escape a single character.